# Single phase welding machine

Tags: welding

In our system netural connection is not available. So we connected phase and earth connection for welding machine supply. But welding machine electrode are not melting properly compared with phase and neutral connection... Kindly tell the reason

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Some more details would likely be helpful (how many phases is your supply? what voltage? etc).

Comment: Are you saying that your current path is from hot to a local ground? If so, the ground path is likely so high in resistance that you cannot get enough current flow at the tip of the electrode. If I understand you correctly, you would need a special low resistance ground.

Comment: What the heck sort of system do you *have*?  It sounds like you really need to be connecting said welding machine *phase-to-phase*...but I'd need the nameplate on the welder and the kind of distribution system you have to know that for sure

Comment: @TPE - OP seriously needs to hire an electrician.  He is inquiring how to hook up a 55KW 3 phase motor in this later post:  http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/106056/how-do-i-size-the-electrical-power-cable

Comment: @Prakash - please hire a qualified electrician before someone gets hurt.

Answer (score 1):

"Earth connection"?  Earth is not a conductor.  Earth does not conduct electricity.  You can't take a tube full of dirt and use it as wire.  The reason we do earthing has nothing to do with earth as a conductor of electricity, it has to do with de-isolating a system.  Still, the only valid current return is one of the conductors.

Even a proper grounding system isn't for conducting electricity.  Don't believe me? Look at any grounding system on heavier conductors like 2/0 AWG (67 mm^2).  The ground isn't 2/0.  It's some little thing like 4 AWG (21 mm^2) - far too small to be a viable conductor for return load.  It is only to handle momentary fault currents for a second, long enough to trip the breaker.

Electricity does not want to get back to earth.  It wants to get back to *source*.

If you ask an earthing system to return more power to source than it is able, it floats, or *energizes at line voltage* everything connected to that earthing system.  This makes the "thing that's supposed to be safe" actually dangerous.   Innocent people get killed this way.

It's not a problem to attach a single-phase load to 3-phase power, you just have to know what you're doing, and to be blunt, *you really don't*.  Call it an American perspective, but we believe *all* life is precious which means safety is vital; and *anybody* can raise their skills, and thus raise their value.  Three-phase power is especially dangerous and not something for amateurs to play with, all due respect.  **GET HELP.** And then if you must do this regularly, *learn*.

Comment: @downvoter please explain, as is the custom on this forum. Since I'm blind guessing here, there was errata in the numbers I threw out for academic purposes, I didn't consider them critical to be accurate since it was a general discussion.  FIXED.